# Big O complexity of this algorithm

Tags: algorithm, big-o, time-complexity

```
IsNumberPrime(int num):
if num <= 1: return False
i = 0
end = sqrt(num)
while ArrayOfPrimes[i] <= end:
  if (num % ArrayOfPrimes[i]) == 0: return False
  i = i + 1
return True
```

This algo checks if the given number is a prime number or not ArrayOfPrimes is array that contains first 1000 primes numbers like [2,3,5,7,11...]. According to my approach since this algo will check the only until the square root of the given number so it should not take more than sqrt(n)/2 so my understanding says it should be sqrt(n).  For example if the number is 19 then it will only check until A[i] <=4.8 i.e only 2 checks.

Comment: Dude, the code.... and there are o(m) primes up to a number m, but not much less. A precise bound for your runtime would be sqrt(n)/log(n)

Comment: You can find out the approximate number of primes less than given n - that would be your complexity. In fact if you ind the EXACT number of primes less than given n - you'll get a lot of money and a prize. As Niklas wrote, it's something like his formula. Read more on wikipedia about primes

Comment: is it something that I can do with num/ln(num) ?

Answer (score 1):

The exact complexity of this algorithm is O(⌊sqrt(num)⌋-1) 
This is number of checks ((num % ArrayOfPrimes[i]) == 0) condition. 
In case number 19 this algorithm will 3 checks: 2, 3, 4

Answer (score 0):

The get the exact complexity, you have to know the number of entrys in `ArrayOfPrimes` that are smaller than `sqrt(num)`. The worst case is, that you have to check all of them.

So if `pi(sqrt(num))` is the [number of primes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) lower than `sqrt(num)` the complexity is

```
O(pi(sqrt(num))) = O(sqrt(num) / log(num))
```